# How do I prevent a bounty from being auto-awarded?

Tags: support, bounties, not-an-answer

I currently have a question with (what I feel is) a very large bounty.  While the question has received some excellent attention, there is only one answer of (in my opinion) somewhat low quality.  As the only answer, I believe it will receive the bounty when it auto-awards.  I feel as though the answer was only posted in order to obtain the bounty auto-award by default.

I have no problem forfeiting the reputation from the bounty, but I'd prefer it to go on an answer of semi-quality, and not have it auto-award to what amounts to an answer for the sake of answering.

I feel that this "bounty sniping" constitutes an actual problem with the system's (ostensibly fake and worthless) currency.  Is there a way to circumvent the auto-award and just have the bounty get discarded?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  The other question asks specifically about *pre-existing* answers, and that's what the answers there focus on.  Preventing the auto-award to a *new* answer is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30338199/168175) your bounty won't get auto-awarded because the answer hasn't met the score requirements for it to be auto awarded.

See ["What is automatic awarding?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) which states:

> The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - **The answer must have a score of at least +2**
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you.  I should have done my research.  Consider this question closed and this answer accepted after the acceptance timeout.